# Google API setApplicationName insert value

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client

I have a problem with setting up the Google API with php. See the code below:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("MY_APP_NAME");
```

What do I have to use for "MY_APP_NAME", is it the appId like "com.mycompany.myapp" or is it the title of the app in Playstore like "Name of my Game"?

Answer (score 12):

If memory serves this is just used in the User-Agent for the HTTP Header.  It doesn't really matter what you set in it.

Example:

> $client->setApplicationName("My first google app");

will do.

Comment: Me to I actually checked the client library code :)

Comment: @Mona935 if this answer solved your problem please select it as accepted answer.