# What is the significance of setApplicationName() in GCP?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-api

I am new to Google Cloud Platform and trying to use Java SDK to create resources in GCP.

I could see the application method in the following code snippet, may take any name while creating my resource like VPC in GCP account.

I would like to know that what is the significance of having this?

Here is the code snippet:

```
Compute compute = new Compute.Builder(GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(), 
    JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), 
        googleCredential)
            .setApplicationName("Google-ComputeSample/0.1") 
            .build();
```

Comment: Can y ou share your dependency version?

Comment: implementation group: 'com.google.apis',  name: 'google-api-services-compute', version: 'v1-rev235-1.25.0'

Comment: I don't know what is the application Name in the compute client builder, it's not so important I think (and I can't answer your question!). However, the library that you use haven't been updated since Feb 2020  and it becomes outdated. The [new one](https://github.com/googleapis/java-compute) is still in alpha but will be released soon. Prefer this one in your developments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Google API docs, [`setApplicationName()`](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-api-client/1.31.5/com/google/api/client/googleapis/services/json/AbstractGoogleJsonClient.Builder.html#setApplicationName-java.lang.String-):

> Sets the application name to be used in the UserAgent header of each request or null for none.

A User-Agent header is used to identify devices requesting online content.
According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40150519/7031308), it appears that it really doesn't matter what value you set in it. It can even be just any random strings if you wanted to. Here's another Google API [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/people/quickstart/java) that uses the same method as example.

As Guillaume mentioned, the library you're using is a Google API Client Library. It's considered complete and is in maintenance mode. This means that Google will still address critical bugs and security issues but will no longer add any new features.

To keep up with the latest client library model, it's a best practice to learn and use the updated [Cloud Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/client-libraries-explained) when accessing Cloud APIs, so I also recommend using it.